# Get the value of a hidden input in server side Php which was set by javascript

Tags: javascript, field, hidden

This wordpress stuff driving me mad again.

I have an output page which uses a short code to call a function (Stores)... the code of which in part is beneath.
It has a dropdown and a table of data, ..the data being dependant on the selected option of the drop down.

I use javascript to set the hidden input...successfully.
In fact I tried a normal, non hidden input as well...same result,..on server side, with$_POST["txtSelection"] or 
$_POST["hdnSelect"]

But when I try get it's value on the php server side code, it is empty,..
How on earth do I retrieve it?

the hidden input is inside the form tag.

```
<?php
function Stores()
{
   global $wpdb;
   global $MyPage;
   $MyPage =  str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
<form name="frmSB_stores" method="post" action="<?php echo $MyPage ?>">  
<input type="hidden" name="hdnSelect" id="hdnSelect" value="">
<input type="text" name="txtSelection" size="19"  id="txtSelection" value="">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SetDDLValueOnChange (objDropDown) {
var objHidden = document.getElementById("hdnSelect");
if ( objDropDown.value.length > '0')
{
    objHidden.value = objDropDown.value; //.substr(0,1);
    //alert(" hdn = " + objHidden.value);
    window.location = '<?=$MyPage;?>' ;
}

}  
</script>
```

the dropdown's markup here,..then

```
<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='3'>
 <?php
$Area = $_POST['txtSelection']; //or $_POST['hdnSelect']
```

which has zilch in it , even though it is set successfully by jvascript

Why is this such an issue in WordPress, 
How do i overcome it.
It's nuts spending a full day on something which should be so trivial (works fine in a normal php situation, os asp or asp.net,..but not in WP.)!
TIA
N

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't submit the form it just tell the browser to goto that page. Hence your value always empty.
`window.location = '<?=$MyPage;?>' ;`

Replace that line with this instead.
`document.forms["frmSB_stores"].submit();`